# How to create a Visual c++ MFC console project in visual studio 2017

Tags: c++, sockets, mfc, console, visual-studio-2017

I've tried to program a socket in Visual Studio 2017, but I can't find the console application in Visual Studio 2017 like this:

[image: description]

Instead, I just see this window
[image: description]

and the wizard like this:
[image: description]

So how can I create a C++ console project with MFC like an earlier version of Visual Studio, or I have to reinstall visual studio 2015.

Comment: You can start a console application and later include MFC through project properties.

Comment: Can you give me a tutorial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio 17 has a different dialog for adding new projects.

1. Select Installed -> Visual C++ -> Windows Desktop -> Windows Desktop Wizard
2. Select Console application with MFC

[image]

Or select Installed -> Visual C++ -> Windows Desktop -> Windows Console App if you don't want MFC or ATL